# vuetify 2.3+ table customSort for single column

Tags: vue.js, sorting, momentjs, vuetify.js

having issues to understand the documentation of vuetifys custom-sort in v-data-table
i don't get the `customSorters?:`
[image: custom-sort]

docs can be found here:
[v-data-table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/)

i try to use the custom-sort only when the column row is 'updated_at' or 'created_at'
because i have a German date time format when i display the result which comes from a SQL date time format

my column values where the customSort should be used looks like this:

[image: updated_at column]

the format is made with moment.js and is `'DD.MM.YYYY - HH:mm:ss'`
i now need a way to compare these rows in a sort function simple with `array.sort()`
this is what i tried for now:

```js
    customSort(items, sortBy, sortDesc) {
      console.log(sortBy)
      if (sortBy.includes('updated_at')) {
        items = items.map((e) => e.updated_at)
        console.log(items)
        items.sort((a, b) => a - b)
      }

      return items
    }
```

this is not working at all

Answer (score 0):

fixed this with help of this post:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57608865/table-sorted-date-not-correct)

instead of formatting the columns when getting them from the api, i use a v-slot and format them inside the table